# Custom content rendering with $page content

Tags: drupal

I created a custom content type, and a view for it.

My page.tpl.php has the following

```
<div class="<?php print (drupal_is_front_page()) ? 'frontBox' : 'container contBox'; ?>">
    <div class="<?php print ($page['categories_blog'] || $page['recent_blog'] || $page['recent_comments']) ? 'globalContant span9' : 'gCont'; ?>">
        <?php  print render($page['content']); ?>

    <?php if ($page['contact_info']): ?>
        <div id="contactInfo">
            <?php print render($page['contact_info']); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

so I have set up my custom content similar to other template objects and they do not get render with the page['content'] yet the one I created gets rendered.

Drupal being so obsfucated is frustrating the hell out of me

Comment: "and a view for it" Do you mean with the views module? "so I have set up my custom content similar to other template objects". What are "template objects"? You may want to rewrite your question as it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Page template is used for all (except overriden) content types. So if you see well nodes in other content types problem is not there. Check on display options for your content type - maybe your fields are set to be hidden?
Also if you have node template for your problematic content type check if you are printing content well there. Try putting some dummy static content (text) to check will it appear. 
Try clearing the cache.